# How to make circular image on android

Tags: android, image

I want to make circular image like this one

[image]

Here is the code, help please,
I have tried the following code, but it's not working fine for me.
Thank you

code:
.....

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=80;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem**

Simple and easy... you should use this method to make image circle shape,

```
 public static Bitmap circleShape(Bitmap preview_bitmap) {

    Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(preview_bitmap.getWidth(),
            preview_bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(preview_bitmap, TileMode.CLAMP,
            TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setShader(shader);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
    c.drawCircle(
            preview_bitmap.getWidth() / 2,
            preview_bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            Math.min(preview_bitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                    preview_bitmap.getHeight() / 2), paint);
    return circleBitmap;

}
```

Whenever you need to make circle bitmap then use

```
  Bitmap uImage = circleShape(uImage);

  ivAddPhoto.setImageBitmap(uImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom image view, I have used it from Q-municate App

```
@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

    public static final String TAG = "RoundedImageView";
    public static final float DEFAULT_RADIUS = 0f;
    private float cornerRadius = DEFAULT_RADIUS;
    public static final float DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0f;
    private float borderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
    private static final ScaleType[] SCALE_TYPES = {ScaleType.MATRIX, ScaleType.FIT_XY, ScaleType.FIT_START, ScaleType.FIT_CENTER, ScaleType.FIT_END, ScaleType.CENTER, ScaleType.CENTER_CROP, ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE};
    private ColorStateList borderColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(RoundedDrawable.DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    private boolean isOval = false;
    private boolean mutateBackground = false;

    private int mResource;
    private Drawable mDrawable;
    private Drawable mBackgroundDrawable;

    private ScaleType mScaleType;

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundedImageView, defStyle, 0);

        int index = a.getInt(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_android_scaleType, -1);
        if (index >= 0) {
            setScaleType(SCALE_TYPES[index]);
        } else {
            // default scaletype to FIT_CENTER
            setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        }

        cornerRadius = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_corner_radius, -1);
        borderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_border_width, -1);

        // don't allow negative values for radius and border
        if (cornerRadius < 0) {
            cornerRadius = DEFAULT_RADIUS;
        }
        if (borderWidth < 0) {
            borderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
        }

        borderColor = a.getColorStateList(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_border_color);
        if (borderColor == null) {
            borderColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(RoundedDrawable.DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
        }

        mutateBackground = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_mutate_background, false);
        isOval = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_oval, false);

        updateDrawableAttrs();
        updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs(true);

        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(int resId) {
        if (mResource != resId) {
            mResource = resId;
            mDrawable = resolveResource();
            updateDrawableAttrs();
            super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
        super.setImageURI(uri);
        setImageDrawable(getDrawable());
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        mResource = 0;
        mDrawable = RoundedDrawable.fromDrawable(drawable);
        updateDrawableAttrs();
        super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        mResource = 0;
        mDrawable = RoundedDrawable.fromBitmap(bm);
        updateDrawableAttrs();
        super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
        setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {
        mBackgroundDrawable = background;
        updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs(true);
        super.setBackgroundDrawable(mBackgroundDrawable);
    }

    public float getCornerRadius() {
        return cornerRadius;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setCornerRadius(float radius) {
        if (cornerRadius == radius) {
            return;
        }

        cornerRadius = radius;
        updateDrawableAttrs();
        updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs(false);
    }

    public void setCornerRadius(int resId) {
        setCornerRadius(getResources().getDimension(resId));
    }

    public float getBorderWidth() {
        return borderWidth;
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(float width) {
        if (borderWidth == width) {
            return;
        }

        borderWidth = width;
        updateDrawableAttrs();
        updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs(false);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int resId) {
        setBorderWidth(getResources().getDimension(resId));
    }

    public int getBorderColor() {
        return borderColor.getDefaultColor();
    }

    public void setBorderColor(ColorStateList colors) {
        if (borderColor.equals(colors)) {
            return;
        }

        borderColor = (colors != null) ? colors : ColorStateList.valueOf(
                RoundedDrawable.DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
        updateDrawableAttrs();
        updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs(false);
        if (borderWidth > 0) {
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the current scale type in use by this ImageView.
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#ImageView_scaleType
     * @see android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType
     */
    @Override
    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
        return mScaleType;
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int color) {
        setBorderColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
    }

    public ColorStateList getBorderColors() {
        return borderColor;
    }

    public boolean isOval() {
        return isOval;
    }

    public void setOval(boolean oval) {
        isOval = oval;
        updateDrawableAttrs();
        updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs(false);
        invalidate();
    }

    public boolean isMutateBackground() {
        return mutateBackground;
    }

    public void setMutateBackground(boolean mutate) {
        if (mutateBackground == mutate) {
            return;
        }

        mutateBackground = mutate;
        updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs(true);
        invalidate();
    }

    private Drawable resolveResource() {
        Resources rsrc = getResources();
        if (rsrc == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Drawable d = null;

        if (mResource != 0) {
            try {
                d = rsrc.getDrawable(mResource);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unable to find resource: " + mResource, e);
                // Don't try again.
                mResource = 0;
            }
        }
        return RoundedDrawable.fromDrawable(d);
    }

    /**
     * Controls how the image should be resized or moved to match the size
     * of this ImageView.
     *
     * @param scaleType The desired scaling mode.
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#ImageView_scaleType
     */
    @Override
    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        assert scaleType != null;

        if (mScaleType != scaleType) {
            mScaleType = scaleType;

            switch (scaleType) {
                case CENTER:
                case CENTER_CROP:
                case CENTER_INSIDE:
                case FIT_CENTER:
                case FIT_START:
                case FIT_END:
                case FIT_XY:
                    super.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    break;
                default:
                    super.setScaleType(scaleType);
                    break;
            }

            updateDrawableAttrs();
            updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs(false);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void updateDrawableAttrs() {
        updateAttrs(mDrawable);
    }

    private void updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs(boolean convert) {
        if (mutateBackground) {
            if (convert) {
                mBackgroundDrawable = RoundedDrawable.fromDrawable(mBackgroundDrawable);
            }
            updateAttrs(mBackgroundDrawable);
        }
    }

    private void updateAttrs(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (drawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
            ((RoundedDrawable) drawable).setScaleType(mScaleType).setCornerRadius(cornerRadius)
                    .setBorderWidth(borderWidth).setBorderColor(borderColor).setOval(isOval);
        } else if (drawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {
            // loop through layers to and set drawable attrs
            LayerDrawable ld = ((LayerDrawable) drawable);
            for (int i = 0, layers = ld.getNumberOfLayers(); i < layers; i++) {
                updateAttrs(ld.getDrawable(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to make it working please use following code in java file after getting the image view from xml:

```
imageView.setOval(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a native solution for this in the new version of the support library called [RoundedBitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html)